# shell script : how to replace file name

Tags: shell, replace

I want to change some file names with full path similar to this:

`/home/guest/test`
⟶ `/home/guest/.test.log`

I tried the command below but it cannot search "/"

```
string="/home/guest/test"
substring="/"
replacement="/."

echo ${string/%substring/replacement}.log
```

Comment: find  /opt -type f -exec echo {} \; | sed 's/\/\([^\/]*\)$/\/.\1.lock/'

Comment: for i in /home/guest/ ; do P=`dirname $i`; F=`basename $i`; echo $P"/."$F".lock"; done

Comment: find . | sed "s/\(.*\)\/\(.*\)/\1\/.\2.lock/"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
for file in /home/guest/*; do 
    name=${file##*/}
    path=${file%/*}
    mv "$file" "$path"'/.'"$name"'.log'
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Created using bash on a mac, so it might work with whatever shell you are using...

```
string="/home/guest/test"
echo $string | sed  's/\/\([^\/]\{0,\}\)$/\/.\1.log/'
```

Using simple shell string replacement wasn't going to work since I know of no way you can target the last occurrence of the / sign as the only replacement.

**Update:**
Actually I came to think of a alternative way if you know that it is always "/two/directories/in"

```
string="/home/guest/test"
firstpartofstring=$(echo $string |  cut -d\/ -f1-3)
lastpartofstring=$(echo $string |  cut -d\/ -f4)
echo ${firstpartofstring}/.${lastpartofstring}.log
```